# JQuery UI (Dialog with Javascript)

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui

how's it going ?

I'm trying to open an dialog component of jquery ui and load the content of the dialog with Ajax (partial view of asp.net mvc) and it's working good. But, the content of Dialog has some javascripts and when the scripts inside the dialog are executed, the behine page lost the style and content disapier  showing only the content of the dialog =/... somebody know how can I resolve this ?

I'd like to show the content like a Dialog of Windows SO with some funcionalities in javascript...

Thanks guys
Att,

Comment: This shouldn't be happening, but in order to understand why, you'll need to provide the code for the code you're loading in the dialog.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Worked a treat for me Zacho, thank you.

```
<div style="display: none;" id="dialog">
    <div class="ajax-loader-long">
        Loading information...<br />
        <img src="images/ajax-loader-long.gif" alt="Loading..." width="220" height="19" />
    </div>
</div>

$("#dialog").load("ajax/budget_overview.php", {SiteID:a.SiteID}, function(response, status, xhr) {
      if (status == "success") {
        $('.ajax-loader-long').hide();
        $("a.tooltip[title]").tooltip({tip:"#tooltip", effect:"fade", fadeOutSpeed:100, predelay:0, position:"top right"});
      }
    }).dialog("open");
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the javascript that is contained in the partial into the callback of your load event when you get the html of that page.  It should execute fine.